# if($(window).width()<=800) не работает в Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, кроссбраузерность

Скрипт гамбургера не работает в Google Chrome, но прекрасно работает в FireFox, если я задаю ему `if($(window).width()<=800){}`. Если же убираю настройки экрана, то тогда работает во всех браузерах.

В чем может быть причина?

```
if ($(window).width() <= 800) {
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $(".cross").hide();
    $(".navigation").hide();
    $(".hamburger").click(function() {
      $(".navigation").slideToggle("slow", function() {
        $(".hamburger").hide();
        $(".cross").show();
      });
    });

    $(".cross").click(function() {
      $(".navigation").slideToggle("slow", function() {
        $(".cross").hide();
        $(".hamburger").show();
      });
    });

  });
}
```

Comment: Какие "настройки экрана" вы ставите и убираете?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваше условие нужно вложить в `.ready()`, а не наоборот:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($(window).width() <= 800) {
    $(".cross").hide();
    $(".navigation").hide();
    $(".hamburger").click(function() {
      $(".navigation").slideToggle("slow", function() {
        $(".hamburger").hide();
        $(".cross").show();
      });
    });

    $(".cross").click(function() {
      $(".navigation").slideToggle("slow", function() {
        $(".cross").hide();
        $(".hamburger").show();
      });
    });
    console.log('Ширина экрана <= 800');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Изначально так и было. Но при этом всё равно не работало

Comment: @nirolo1 Ну вы видете ведь, что данный код работает?)

Comment: По какой то причине он работает через раз

Comment: Но то что я поставил ширину после ready помогло

Comment: правда через раз...)